# Printing HTML Response in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting JSON response, and the same response I am printing on Lightning Component, the issue I am facing is I am getting response in HTML and I want print the output of the HTML.

Here is the response I am getting

```
[
check=1,
xyz=0, 
date=Mon May 08 14:34:27 EDT 2017, 
Fax=<a href='mailto:pdf.0987654321.abhi@gmail.com?Subject=Send a PDF to this record' title='email to this record'>+1 (098) 765-4321</a>
]
```

and I want to print fax as output mailto link,

In Component I am doing like this below

```
{v.Data.Fax}
```

But getting the output like this

```
<a href='mailto:pdf.0987654321.abhi@gmail.com?Subject=Send a PDF to this record' title='email to this record'>+1 (098) 765-4321</a>
```

Comment: Can try [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_unescapedHtml.htm)

Comment: you are the best , it worked :)

Comment: I'll convert the comment as answer, accept it so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [aura:unescaptedHTML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_unescapedHtml.htm) to render HTML content in view. Also be very cautions when using this component because it might open a security vector as the doc states:

> This component outputs value as unescaped HTML, which introduces the
>   possibility of security vulnerabilities in your code. You must
>   sanitize user input before rendering it unescaped, or you will create
>   a cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability.

So only use `<aura:unescapedHtml>` with trusted or sanitized sources of data.

For sanitizing the HTML content you can use any of the below libraries:

1.[sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)

2.[DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

3.[secureFilter](https://github.com/salesforce/secure-filters) which mentioned in the [Lightning Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security)